# AngularJS two-way data binding won't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been experiencing angular for about a month now.
I'm familiar with all the core aspects of it, but i've encountered a problem that I don't understand. 
I have 2 directives - one is the parent, and the other is the child. 
The child gets 3 parameters from the parent - 2 of them pass through, but when I debug and check the 3rd one - it's undefined.
Child Directive -

```
angular.module('management').directive('timeFrame', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/Client/directives/timeFrame/timeFrame.html',
    scope: {
        timeFrame: '=',
        deleteFrameFunction: '&',
        index: '@'
    }
```

The child directive is being used in the following way :

```
<div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="timeFrame in ad.timeFrames">
  <time-frame index="{{$index}}" timeFrame="timeFrame" deleteFrameFunction="(function() {doStuff;})"></time-frame>
</div>
```

All the parameters pass through, but timeFrame which is undefined.
I tried changing the way I pass it to `{{timeFrame}}` or :`ad.timeFrames[{{$index}}]` and many other ways that failed.
I need to pass this parameter using a two-way binding because this directive will modify it and the parent directive has to be aware of it.
I haven't done anything different than other directives that worked for me in the same way.

Any help / explanations will be appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your html, the variable $index should be index (no $)

Comment: Have you tried `ad.timeFrames[$index]` ?

Comment: Btw, instead of two-way binding can you just pass the value down and then later use `$emit` to send an event to the parent ? in parent scope you can `$on` to listen to the event.

Comment: @SambhavGore The current best-practices dictate you should move away from eventing down the scope chain where explicit binding will suffice.  There's no reason to introduce additional events here.  This is especially true if you are writing Angular 1.x code with the intention of converting to Angular 2.x down the road.

Comment: @DavidL thanks, I would love to read more on it. Because as per my understanding, in Angular2 it is 2-way data binding that is discouraged and events will be the way to notify parents of the changes done down the line. Any links you can point to ?

Comment: @SambhavGore read through the upgrade guide (you can jump ahead to https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#upgrading-controllers-to-components).  You'll notice that nowhere are they using eventing as it exists today in Angular 1 and events in Angular 2 are used for triggering DOM interactions, not sharing data.  Everything is done via injected components and injected data.  In addition, 2 way binding is absolutely encouraged in Angular 2, where it makes sense.  However, they have provided far more flexibility in binding to prevent waste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your naming convention is incorrect.  When binding to directive-scoped properties, the same camelCase to hyphen naming convention that is used for directives applies.

```
time-frame="timeFrame"
```

However, since this will conflict with your directive name, you should use a different scope property name.

directive:

```
scope: {
    boundTimeFrame: '=',
    deleteFrameFunction: '&',
    index: '@'
}
```

template:

```
<time-frame index="{{$index}}" bound-time-frame="timeFrame" 
    delete-frame-function="(function() {doStuff;})"></time-frame>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Feeling a bit silly right now.
I'd like to know how come the deleteFrameFunction did pass through even though the naming convention was incorrect for it too?
Thanks again David.

Comment: @DotnetProg correct, that would also have been "incorrect" as well, but only from a "style" perspective.. It "worked" because '&' allows you to invoke a parent function and pass a parameter into it, instead of binding something from the parent to the directive's isolated scope.  In this case, the "parent function" is simply the anonymous function you define, so nothing needs to be referred to.

Comment: The only explanation that I can think of is that you referenced it by attribute, not by scope which would have bound the value across.  In order for it to be bound to scope it must follow the appropriate naming convention.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again for your time! :)